# Fading Toolbar in Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, navigation-drawer

I have created "**Navigation drawer**" demo. I am facing an issue with a fading effect (transparent background in both **"toolbar+statusbar"**). In some fragments it does not apply fading effect.

A Parallax effect is not required just toolbar+statubar behind Fragment B background image

i.e Navigation Drawer inside 3 fragment

1)FragmentA
2)Fragment B
3) Fragment C

I require Fading effect in Fragment B, but I don't know how to apply such type transparent background effect.

Please check sample [image: I used this image google search engine]attached screenshot.

How to apply such type of fading background ?

Comment: You mean transparent background ?

Comment: ya but only on some fragment in navigation drawer